# How can I build static bz2 library?

Tags: compiling, makefile

I need the static library libbz2.a to compile a repo I have cloned from github.  I have a dynamic library, libbz2.so.1.04, but there doesn't seem to be a static library. I found a solution to the same problem on centOS at https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=52129, but I don't know how to accomplish this on Ubuntu.  I don't know anything about this, and I'll probably need as detailed an answer as the one given at the above link.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this was easy, once I figured out how to download the source.  I went into System Settings/Software & Updates and enabled downloading source.  Then I went to a temporary folder and did `apt-get source bzip2`.  Among other things, this downloaded a file named bzip2_1.0.6.orig.tar.bz2.  When I extracted the archive it had two Makefiles, one for the static library and one for the .so file.  The one named 'Makefile' was for the .a file, so I just had to do `make`.